# Rails 4: Return all instances from a where call

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a status integer column in a invoices table

```
def change
  create_table :invoices do |t|
    t.integer   :status
  end
end
```

I do a find like this

```
def find_status(status)
  Invoice.where(status: status)
end
```

This is great when I want to find all invoices with, say status 1.

But, sometimes I want to the find_status method return all invoices?

I could solve this with a if statement, but my question is;

Can I pass something into the find_status method that will return all invoices?

PS: After reviewing this question I understand if someone get the temptation to suggest other solutions to the problem. Please just look at this question as a "prof of concept kind of question"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put an array or a range into the method call assuming you've not got hundreds of statuses, but unable to resist the temptation - if you want them all I'd avoid the method call and just do `Invoice.all`

Comment: Didn't mention range because I didn't know whether your statuses were numerical or something like "Active", "Complete" e.t.c.

Comment: They are so a range is perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is nearly impossible to do that as `where` doesn't support wildcards in this scenario and options like huge range result in very unclean code. But you might use `Invoice.all` call instead of calling this method.

Comment: Nothing is impossible. I can use a range like this 0..99999999999

Comment: @AndreasLyngstad better?

Answer (score 0):

You can change your find_status method like below if you insist on using the same method for both.

```
def find_status(status = nil)
  status.nil? ? Invoice.all.to_a : Invoice.where(status: status)
end
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. This uses if else as I said I didn't want

Comment: Yeah...I get it. But, I thought your intention was to use the same method. I wasn't aware of this pluck method. In that case you can go with what @Baloo suggested.

Comment: Or I should have suggested `find_status Invoice.all.to_a`

Comment: The all call does not do lazy loading. It loads everything at the moment it's called not when its used as the where call does.

Answer (score 0):

It is absolutely impossible ! And hopefully, that would be a real security issue if we could do that.
Nevertheless, if you don't mind a lack of security, you can still write something like

```
def find_status(status)
  Invoice.where("status = #{status}")
end
```

And then

```
find_status(1) #=> All invoices with the status 1
find_status('status') #=> All invoices :)
```

But again, what I did was exploiting a lack of security ! 
And as you said, you could easily use an if or a ? condition statement

Actually ! You can do that:

```
find_status Invoice.pluck(:status)
```

It works without changing your method :)

Comment: When we have something achievable why still propose the method which lacks security. Can you please delete the previous proposed way (the one which lacks security)?

Comment: Because knowing security issues is a good way to avoid them :)

Comment: Well why did I miss this thought? ;) Well, in that case, we ought to know that.